# NSIS 2.51 to 3.0 upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installation, nsis

We've been using NSIS 2.51 for a while. Noticed that 3.0 came out in July. I looked through the changelog on the official site and didn't see any backwards-compatibility-breaking, but thought I'd ping SO to see if anyone's had any issues when going to 3.0.

Also wondering if there were any big changes aside from Unicode to be excited about? I'm assuming we still can't do native arrays without a plugin. :)

Answer (score 1):

Issues:

- MUI LangDll dialog might not display all languages correctly in Ansi installers but the list uses English names by default now IIRC.

New features:

- Win 8.1 and 10 manifest support.
- A couple of Unicode-only translations.
- System plugin can call functions by ordinal.
- MakeNSIS can create 64-bit installers if the 64-bit stubs are present (Undocumented).

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use NSIS 3.0. It is pretty stable and almost 100% compatible with NSIS 2 code.

There are some new commands (Unicode, File operations, ...) and some commands have different parameters but there are no serious issues with it. And also security was improved (dll hijacking), added some fixes etc.

Recommended by me :)

Comment: The dll hijacking protection has been backported to 2.51.